# Custom logger using a service needs same instance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, iloggerfactory

I wrote a custom logger using the `ILoggingBuilder` and the `ILoggerProvider` pattern as describe [in the .net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider#create-the-custom-logger)

My logger needs a service build in the app, I was able to pass the service using the `ServiceProvider` but unfortunetly the instance is duplicated (even if the service is declared as a singleton)

Here is a sample of the code :

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
                {
                    if (args is not null)
                    {
                        _ = configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                    builder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true))                

                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    
                    services.AddServices();
                    serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                }
                )
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, loggingFactory) =>
                {

                    loggingFactory
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddEventLog()                            
                            .AddFile("Logs/worker-{Date}.txt")
                            .AddCustomFormatter(serviceProvider.GetService<IMycustomService>());
                });
```

I've tried many approches but I was not able to use the same instance in my servicesColletion and in my custom logger

Any hep would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that inside `AddCustomFormatter()` you are manually creating an instance of your logging provider and that's why you are passing the resolved instance of `IMyCustomService`. Instead of doing it, let DI handle it for you. Register your custom logger provider like this, to add it to the list of `ILoggerProvider` available implementations:

```cs
public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomFormatter(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, CustomLoggerProvider>());

    return builder;
}
```

Then your custom logger provider can require `IMyCustomService` without the need for explicit supplying of its dependencies.

```cs
public class CustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IMyCustomService myCustomService;

    public CustomLoggerProvider(IMyCustomService myCustomService)
    {
        this.myCustomService = myCustomService;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomLogger(myCustomService);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```